# Should i prefix name attributes in angular components?

Tags: angular, radio-button, components

I have radio buttons in a custom angular component like below. I am using this custom component in my main component. And in my main component, I am using the exactly the same buttons. The problem is they are not working properly if i do not change the name attributes.

Custom component code is below.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label">{{'dvTrackVehicleNumber.showSettings'|translate}}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label  style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active':showSettings=='NONE'}">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]="showSettings" type="radio" value="NONE" name="showSettings" > {{'dvTrackVehicleNumber.showNoSettings'|translate}}
                                </label>
                                <label  style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active':showSettings=='CONFIGMAIN'}">
                                     <input  [(ngModel)]="showSettings" type="radio" value="CONFIGMAIN" name="showSettings" > {{'dvTrackVehicleNumber.configMain'|translate}}
                                </label>
                                <label  style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active':showSettings=='CONFIGSETTINGS'}">
                                     <input  [(ngModel)]="showSettings" type="radio" value="CONFIGSETTINGS" name="showSettings" > {{'dvTrackVehicleNumber.configSettings'|translate}}
                                </label>
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**If i change name="showSettings" to name="showSettingsModal" in all radio buttons inside my custom component and leave it as name="showSettings" in the main component system works fine.** 
Obviously this is causing a conflict.. But i am curious there are lots of custom components on the web which you can use and they are not causing any problems. 
Should i prefix all my name attributes or there is a better way ? or maybe i am doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a radio button group, and the main component is embedding this custom component (child component), the DOM will be there on the same page. Hence the conflict.

Better use different group name as you had already done.

Comment: Thanks, how does commonly used custom components on the web avoid this issue ?

Comment: We can prefix it with the component name as a best practice.